# How to check when the dropdown list has been selected/changed in php or how to keep the selected new value

Tags: php, html

I am doing an e-commerce website using PHP.

I have a dropdown list for the all the countries and each time the user selects a country, a form will be submitted to get the shipping amount. Everything is fine when the customer checkout as a guest.

When a customer is signed in, the shipping address will be auto-populated with the last purchase details of the customer. However when the signed in customer wants to select another country for the shipping address, the page keeps on loading the same address as what was on the last purchase.

How can I keep the new country selected by the customer on the dropdown list?

This is the html code for the dropdown list:

```html
<select class="span6" name="country" id="shipping_country">
    <option value="">--Select Country--</option>
    <?php
        foreach ($countries as $country) {
            $selected = "";
            if ($shipping_country == $country["country"]) {
                $selected = "selected";
            }
            print("<option value='{$country["country"]}' {$selected}>{$country["country"]}</option>");
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

This is my php code:

```
if ($this->input->cookie('affiliate_id')) {

    $data["affiliate_login"] = "hide";
    $result = $this->affiliate_model->get_affiliate_detail($this->input->cookie('affiliate_id'));
    $data["affiliate_data"] = $result;

    // Use the info from last purchase.
    $result = $this->affiliate_model->last_buy_record($this->input->cookie('affiliate_id'));

    if ($result) {
        $data["affiliate_shipping_data"] = $result;
        $country = $result["shippingCountry"];
        $data["shipping_country"] = $country;
   }
```

The above php code enables me to get the details from the last purchase and auto-select the country on the dropdown list.

The new code I want to add to get the country that is newly selected is the following:

```
$country = $this->session->userdata("shipping_country");
$data["shipping_country"] = $country;
```

However, I wanted to add an 'if condition' to check when the dropdown list has been selected or changed. How can check that? Or is there another way to keep the country that was selected by the user?

Comment: Just get the country from the cookies, and have the method that gets the last shipping details check if there is already a country in the cookies, if not, default to the last shipping details. Have your dropdown post and overwrite the cookie country setting.

Comment: Are you using an ajax request to get the new shipping information or are you reloading the page?

Comment: I would think in a users 'current session', if the country has yet to be set (its empty), then it would pull their prior purchase to set for their session. Then use what is set in the session. If the country changes (post/ajax submit)... update the session value.